# Julia working with large arrays, is there any memory/speed advantage to using Int8 vs Int64?

Tags: arrays, integer, julia

Julia 1.5.3 on Ubuntu.
I'm writing an iterative model, form of microsimulation and converting from R.  The array sizes can get quite large as the population grows yet are all comprised of Integers, and small ones at that.  Is there any advantage to using Int8 in this case in terms of either memory or speed, as opposed to what appears to me to be the default of Int64?

Is there a way to tell Julia, some global/universal setting that can be changed to use Int8 as default rather than Int64 unless otherwise instructed?

Have come across my first problem.  I have a function that works with Int8 values, but when I call it as such:

```
Pop = InitialPop(StaNum, LayNum, MaxSts, MaxPar, MaxDay, MaxTrt)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching InitialPop(::Int8, ::Int8, ....
```

This function simply creates an initial starting "population" or organisms so my question is:

1. Is it better to just use default Int64 methods and convert the whole array to Int8 after it is produced or
2. What do I need to do to make it all work in Int8 and overcome the above error?

Elucidation of glaring flaws in my logic most welcome!
Thx. J

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the operations on `Int8`s will be much faster and will consume less memory - Int8 takes 1 byte of RAM while `Int64` takes 8 bytes of RAM (see the benchmark below).
However, for the meta-parameters of the model (such as population size) it is OK to stick with `Int64`s. They are used only once and perhaps not a central part of your computation.

Consider the following two vectors:

```
a = rand(Int8(0):Int8(127), 1000)
b = rand(0:127, 1000)
```

Let us see how much time and memory is needed to substract 5 from each element of those vectors:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime $a.-Int8(5);
  118.053 ns (1 allocation: 1.06 KiB)

julia> @btime $b.-Int64(5);
  581.959 ns (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)
```

You can see that the speedup is 4x and the memory consumption is 8x less.

Comment: Thanks for that, but why is my function call throwing errors?  If my understanding is correct they are not meta-parameters but the actual data to be stored in the arrays as the simulation progresses and time passes.  Do I have to specify at every step of the way that I want to use Int8?

Comment: Could you post a MWE to see the function or struct you are trying to create? The error is telling you that you did not define a method that accepts those argument types.

Comment: Also, side note, in case you constained the types in your function, maybe you can try to avoid that entirely, and let the compiler spit out specialized functions for each combination of types you throw at it (I.e., do `foo(x,y) = ...` instead of `foo(x::Int8, y::Int8) = ...`).

Comment: @JimMaas Yes you need perhaps to re-engineer the functions. Actually there is now good way to downgrade all `Int`s other than trying to run a 32-bit Julia - in that case `Int` will point to `Int32` rather than `Int64`. Like @Benoit mentioned to tell something more we would need to see the code.

Comment: As others have said, it is hard to answer a question about your function, if you aren't sharing some code, at _least_ the function signature. Still, I feel pretty confident that if you change your function definition to `function InitialPop(StaNum::Integer, LayNum::Integer, ...)` or even totally remove the types from the signature, then that specific error will go away.

Comment: Thanks all, went back and incrementally worked through it and error disappeared!  Not sure what it was.